# Second supplemental law of Eisenstein Reciprocity

Tags: number-theory

The second supplemental law is stated in several sources as follows:

$(\frac{1-\zeta_m}{a})_m = (\frac{\zeta_m}{a})_m^{\frac{m-1}{2}}$

See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_reciprocity,
Franz Lemmermeyer "Reciprocity Laws".

I have found an error in this formulation of the law.
Take for example, $m=5, a=2$.
Then $(\frac{1-\zeta_5}{2})_5 \equiv (1-\zeta_5)^{(2^4-1)/5}=(1-\zeta_5)^3 \equiv (\zeta_5)^4 \mod 2$.
But the formula in the law gives $\zeta_5$.

Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

You are right: the claim in the book is said to follow from the fact that $(\frac{\alpha}a)_m = 1$ if $\alpha$ is real and coprime to $a\ell$. Applying 
this to  $\alpha = (1-\zeta)^2\zeta^{-1}$ yields 
$(\frac{1-\zeta}a)^2 = (\frac{\zeta}a)$, and now the correct claim follows
by raising this to the $\frac{\ell+1}2$-th power (and not $\frac{\ell-1}2$).